# How to exclude files for MISRA compliance in make file

Tags: c, misra

I have a repository, which is working on MISRA compliance. In that repository I’ve integrated another repository which does not have any MISRA rules. While compiling the code I’m getting MISRA errors. Unfortunately I cannot change anything in the repository which I’ve integrated as it will cause warranty issues.

Is there any way to exclude the files from MISRA rules in **Makefile**?

Edit :- Make file snippet

```
CFLAGS = -o "$@" --misrac=$(MISRA_RULES) --misra-version2004

ADDITIONAL_INCLUDES = \
-I"$(SRC_DIR)" \ 
-I"$(SRC_DIR)\SW" \ 
-I"$(SRC_DIR)\SW\ADDED_REPO" \

MISRA_RULES = 1.1,1.2,10.1,.....9.3 (all rules of MISRA)
```

PS - I cannot change MISRA rules, I cannot change any code in ADDED_REPO. All I can do is change make mile. I don’t have to apply the MISRA rules to ADDED_REPO.

Comment: Your question seems to be about a specific linter, you need to tell us which one and how i is currently integrated in your makefile.

Comment: @julaine I've added the snippet of makefile.. hope that helps

Comment: I still cannot tell what linter you are using from your snippet. Since you set the misra-version in the CFlags, I suspect the linter is integrated into your compiler or that it is a compiler-plugin. What compiler are you using?

Comment: look for stuff like pclint, flexelint, coverity, ldra testbed to find out what your linter might be.

Comment: @julaine it’s Tasking compiler based on gcc. The MISRA rules doesn’t seem to be integrated.

Comment: The solution is most likely to set an option on the linter. You need to find out which linter you are using. Alternatively, let the linter check everything, then filter the output to only see the violations in files where you care about non-compliance.

Comment: According to Tasking, they have MISRA support built-in these days. Simply make 2 different make files for 2 different projects? Or better yet, don't muck around with make files at all, as if we're still in the 1990s, and instead use a programming IDE with a project per project.

Comment: This is absurd.  If your project is obligated to comply with MISRA rules, then even using an external library that does not comply defeats the purpose.  Much more so actually integrating non-(MISRA-)conforming code directly.  What you need to do is either get your MISRA compliance restriction lifted for the entire project, or avoid use of the non-conforming library altogether.

Comment: @JohnBollinger why is "don't do that" the answer to every SO-question? It is not unusual at all to follow coding-guidelines in new code only.

Comment: @julaine, I speculate that "don't do that" is a relatively common answer because many of those asking questions here do not have enough experience to already know not to do that.

Comment: Surely the simple answer is to have one list of source files that you use {OPT_MISRA} and one list of source files with opt {OPT_NOMISRA}

Comment: @JohnBollinger Not so absurd. A product could be used in multiple ways, for example for non-critical purposes if the application doesn't call for them. Imagine some manner of fieldbus communication device. Depending on if you communicate with safety-related computers or just some PC, you can either link in a CAN bus driver or an Ethernet driver with the corresponding HALs - the rest of the code being shared. And the safety-related, MISRA compliant code will require that no unrelated code that is never called is present, so you need a separate project then.

Comment: What _is_ absurd is keeping a single project, running on a single microcontroller, then "isolate" the safety-related parts and claim that only those need to conform with safety standards. As if the rest of the code is running in a vacuum isolated from the safety-related parts, when it's actually using the very same CPU, sharing the same interrupts and hardware etc etc. That's plain quackery, but I've heard several horror design stories like that here on SE...

Comment: Well, @Lundin, your latter case is mostly what I had in mind when I wrote that comment.  Nevertheless, if management's existing standard is already MISRA compliance, then allowing new code that does not comply establishes *de facto* at least a more nuanced policy.  If management is not prepared to lay that out in detailed writing, then chaos ensues.  And maybe lawsuits.

Comment: @julaine I can see a bin folder in my repo which has the executables. The path is given in the Makefile for that. It has files such as amk.exe, CTC.exe, cctc.exe. The ctc.exe is getting executed while code is getting compiled.

Comment: @Andrew can you please tell in detail. I’m new to Makefile. Appreciate your help I want to try this in make file

Comment: @Fatpanda could that be ctc++ from testwell maybe?

Comment: @Fatpanda - I assume your makefile has a {$SRC} or similar list of source files?  The problem we have here, is there is not a "helpful" answer as yours is a very specific question.  Likewise, with my MISRA hat on, I'd like to discourage your approach!